# Serialization Exception when saving an instance of a class to ApplicationSettings

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a custom class with quite a few properties and when I create an instance of this class I add it to isolated storage so that it can be retrieved later, however once i've saved one if I try to save another I get this exception:

Type `System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush` with data contract name `SolidColorBrush(http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Windows.Media)` is not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the `KnownTypeAttribute` attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to `DataContractSerializer`.

One of my properties is a Brush however I don't set this property here initially so why is the exception only coming up when I save a second instance?

Any Help would be brilliant thanks :)

Comment: Could you provide your code, please? Anyway, this link could help you [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2009/04/21/understanding-known-types.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Any object that you want to save to isolated storage (using the [IsolatedStorageSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class) has to be serializable using the [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

The [SolidColorBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (and any [Brush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brush%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for that matter) is not market with serializable, so that is the problem here!

To solve it, I suggest you just save the color of the brush (instead of the actual Brush object) and then retrieve it and make a new SolicColorBrush object.

Comment: I learnt the hard way that you should never serialise any UI related item *as the UI item* - instead translate it into your own neutral data structure and save it, that way you don't get hit with complications when you change the UI and your serialised data is now out of date.

Comment: Thanks :) My only problem is that the reason I have a brush property is because I have a listbox which displays all instances of this class that I've saved so I don't know how to set the colour of the individual listbox items without binding the foreground property to the colour property of my class instance. Do you know any other way I could achieve this effect?

Comment: If your using Binding, you can create a converter to convert a Color to a SolidColorBrush! [Cimbalino Windows Phone Toolkit](https://github.com/Cimbalino/Cimbalino-Phone-Toolkit) has one, you can add a reference to the project, or just copy the converter [here](https://github.com/Cimbalino/Cimbalino-Phone-Toolkit/blob/master/src/Cimbalino.Phone.Toolkit/Converters/ColorToBrushConverter.cs)!